Finding intersection numbers for projective curves $Y^2Z-X(X-2Z)(X+Z)$ and $Y^2+X^2-2XZ$
I'm having a trouble doing problem 5.3a in Fulton's Algebraic Curves. The problem asks to find the intersection points and intersection numbers at these points for the curve: $F = Y^2Z-X(X-2Z)(X+Z)$ and $G = Y^2+X^2-2XZ$.
I know that the points of intersection are $[0:0:1]$, $[2:0:1]$, $[1: \sqrt{2}i: -\frac{1}{2}]$, and $[1: -\sqrt{2}i: -\frac{1}{2}]$.
Dehomogenizing $F$ and $G$ in regard to $Z$ for the first two points give:
$F_{*} = Y^2-X(X-2)(X+1)$ and $G_{*} = Y^{2}+X^{2}-2X$. It is clear that $(0,0)$ is a simple point on both of these. $(2,0)$ is also a simple point by computing the derivatives. Therefore, the intersection numbers at the first two points should both be $1$, as they are of multiplicity $1$ and $F_{*}$ and $G_{*}$ do not share a component.
Doing the same in regard to $X$ for the last two points gives: $F_{*} = Y^{2}Z-(1-2Z)(1+Z)$ and $G_{*} = (Y^{2}+1-2Z)$. It should be clear that the derivative at $Y$ is non-zero as $Y$ is not-zero. This also leads to the conclusion that the intersection numbers at the last two points should also both be $1$.
However, by Bezout's theorem, we are supposed to add up the intersection numbers and get $6$, instead of $4$. Where did I do wrong?
Thank you!

You looked at the curves individually and didn't intersect! The curves are tangent in the two first points.

@Jan-MagnusØkland I'm sorry but what does this mean?

@ccream you found the intersection points and found that they are simple points on the curves, but you didn't compute the intersection number there

@SergeyGuminov I see! I wanted to use the property that I(P, $F\cap G$) is the product of the multiplicities if they share no tangent. In the (0,0) case, for example, the tangents are -2x and 2x; they represent the same line although they are different in formula. I guess that's where I did wrong. Thx

The inteersections stay away from $z=0,$ so let's use the standard affine open $z=1.$ The geometric intersection comes out as the sum of the ideals.
R=QQ[x,y]
I=ideal(y^2-x*(x-2)*(x+1))+ideal(x^2+y^2-2*x)
primaryDecomposition I -- {ideal(x,y^2), ideal(x-2,y^2), ideal(x+2,y^2+8)}

The intersections are double points at $(0,0)$ and $(2,0),$ and Bezout holds. 
If you want you can think of them as limits of $\langle x,y^2-\epsilon \rangle$ and $\langle x-2,y^2-\epsilon \rangle$ and use conservation of number.

Hi, thank you for your solution, but may I ask how did you see the intersection number directly from the graph? I know they share the same tangent, so the intersection number > 1.

@ccream The intersection number is from the ideal, not the graph
